# ImageMagick get wrong result when converting a pdf to jpg

Tags: tikz-pgf, convert

My LaTeX code is listed below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) [pattern=north west lines, minimum size = 5cm] at (0  , 0  ) {};
\node (B) [pattern=north east lines, minimum size = 5cm] at (4cm, 4cm) {};

\node [circle,draw=red,fill=red] at (A.center) {};
\node [circle,draw=red,fill=red] at (B.center) {};

\draw [|<->|,color=red,line width=1pt] ([yshift=6pt]A.north west) -- node [fill=white] {Cross} ([yshift=6pt]B.north west|-A.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The generated PDF is:
[image]

But when I converted the pdf file using the following command, I did not get the same result, as shown below. In fact, the result is wrong because of the border of the node `Cross` and the black line.

[image]

---

## Update

The command used to convert pdf to jpg is

> convert test.pdf test.jpg

The version of ImageMagic is

```
C:\users\test\> convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.3-2 Q16 x64 2016-10-02 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

I also tested png using the following command.

> convert test.pdf test.png

However, still the problem.

[image]

Comment: The used command for ImageMagick is missing, and I am not able to reproduce it using `convert test.pdf test.jpg`. For me this does not seem like a LaTeX problem. Instead of JPG I would probably use PNG to avoid problems with the used compression (something like `convert -density 300 test.pdf test.png`).

Comment: As @ep said, PNG is the proper choice for artificial (drawn) graphical material. JPEG should only be used for photographs.

Comment: Do you really need to `fill=white` the node background? This might be the reason for the artifact at the node edge produced by the JPEG algorithm. Anyways, don't use JPEG here.

Comment: Viewer and rendering issues are off-topic.

Comment: @AlexG Yes, I just need that the test on the line. This is the only way I have found.

Answer (score 1):

The `edge` operation could be used to draw line segments *between* nodes, removing the need for setting the node background.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) [pattern=north west lines, minimum size = 5cm] at (0  , 0  ) {};
\node (B) [pattern=north east lines, minimum size = 5cm] at (4cm, 4cm) {};

\node [circle,draw=red,fill=red] at (A.center) {};
\node [circle,draw=red,fill=red] at (B.center) {};

\coordinate (a) at ([yshift=6pt]A.north west);
\coordinate (b) at ([yshift=6pt]B.north west|-A.north);
% put the "Cross" node, without drawing line
\path (a) -- node[red] (c) {Cross} (b);
% draw line segments
\path[red,line width=1pt,->|] (c) edge (a) edge (b);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, I have found the solution for the problem mentioned here.

Here is the solution:

Add the following lines into the `tex` source.

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
...
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill [color = white] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
\end{scope}
```